# Filter matrix rows based on value of function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, filter, row

This seems like a simple question but I have been unable to find an answer anywhere. If I have a Matlab matrix `A` consisting of an arbitrary number of rows, how would I filter these rows based on the value of some function `f` (the argument of which is a row vector)? In other words, how would I keep only the rows of matrix `A` for which `f` is `true`? I tried

```
A(f(A(:)), :)
```

but to no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly does `f(A(:))` return?

Comment: `f` should probably take `A` as an argument and not `A(:)` so you don't lose the information about what elements make a row. Then all it needs to do is output a vector of type logical (which happens by default if created through a condition like `==` or `>` etc) and it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14951554/1714410) answered, you can filter the rows of a matrix according to a logical vector. Let `selectRows` be a logical vector with `numel(selectRows) == size(A,1)` with `true` for rows to be kept, and `false` for rows to be discarded. Then:

```
A( ~selectRows, : ) = [];
```

Will remove all rows for which `selectRows == false`.

Now, the question is how to generate the logical vector `selectRows` using the function `f`?

If `f` knows how to process multiple rows, and return multiple `true`/`false` values accordingly, then

```
selectRows = f(A);
```

Should do the trick.

However, if `f` only knows how to process one row at a time you will need to loop through the rows. One way of doing so would be

```
selectRows = cellfun( @f, mat2cell( A, ones(size(A,1)), size(A,2) ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is a little unclear (you should provide your criteria for filtering) but it sounds like you just need to make use of Matlab's logical indexing.

Try out this very contrived example:

```
A = rand(7)
A = A(logical([1 1 0 0 0 1 1]), :)
```

Here I filter out rows 3 - 5 by telling Matlab which rows and which columns (all of them in our case) to keep.

You can avoid the ugly casting by creating the vectors as a conditional:

```
A = rand(5)
A([1 0 1 1 0] == 1, :)
```

Of course if we knew your filtering criteria then it would be much simpler to create the logical indexes this way. So as an example, lets assume you want to filter all rows whose sum is greater than 10. Step 1 is to find those rows (either the rows to keep or the rows to filter, it doesn't matter):

```
rowsToFilter = sum(A, 2) > 10;
```

Try that in the command line without the `;` and you'll see it sums along the rows (the `2` in the sum argument) and chooses only those that are greater than `10` by creating a vector of logicals (Matlab's boolean type). Now to filter A it's just:

```
A(rowsToFilter, :) = [];
```

The = [] sets the rows we want to filter to empty vectors which Matlab understands as removing those elements from the matrix.

You could do the same thing by choosing the rows to keep like this:

```
rowsToKeep = sum(A, 2) <= 10;
A = A(rowsToKeep, :);
```

You'll notice that this last form is very similar to what you tried with `f(A) = sum(A, 2) <= 10`